# ReactiveSearch - Multilist react prop does not filter itself

Tags: reactjs, opensearch, reactivesearch

On previous version of ReactiveSearch if you had a multilist component that referenced itself in the react prop the component would rerender with a more narrow list. In this example if an author is chosen a list would return with a more narrow list of authors related to the author chosen. It seems like in ReactiveSearch V4 this is not possible. Can someone point me in the right direction of we might be able to accomplish this. Should I make a controlled component and transform the list with a another query?

See how the react prop references `authorList` which is its own ID

```
<MultiList
    componentId="authorList"
    compoundClause="filter"
    dataField="author.keyword"
    title="author"
    size={30}
    queryFormat="and"
    showCheckbox={true}
    showCount={true}
    placeholder="Search for Authors"
    react={{
        and: ['authorList'],
    }}
    showFilter={true}
    filterLabel="Author"
    URLParams={true}
    loader="Loading ..."
      
/>
```

Comment: I will note that if I manually refresh with filter selected it will do the functionality I want since the url params are on.